# how to custom error msg with PHP if can't connect to web service (JSON)

Tags: php, json

i'm connecting to a webservice using PHP and JSON. the connection is good but i want to add 2 error messages when (1) connection to the webservice is lost and (2) if webservice returns a http 500 error.

any ideas on how to do that?? i'm new to json so not sure how to do that...

this is how i connect and get data form the webservice

```
$url = "http://webservice.com/{$account}?loc={$loc}"; 
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
```

Comment: Won't the connection to the web service be lost at the end of every request?

Comment: For the 500 error you'll want to check the HTTP response code.  I'm unsure how to do that w/ file_get_contents, but a stream context could be what you need.  You could also get it more easily w/ curl, but that would complicate you initial code (could be worth it though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For error 1:

`file_get_contents` will return `FALSE` if what it is trying to load fails.

For error 2:

Depending on what your HTTP Error 500 outputs on the page, you can simply use `file_get_contents` and look for a certain string indicating the error using `strpos` and act accordingly.

**Reference**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: thanks. i thnk it works. gotta do more testing but think i'm good.